# how to load different tables from different excel sheets using ssis

Tags: ssis, extract

For example;
 i have a,b,c,d,e tables & iam having one excel file which is having s1,s2,s3,s4,s5 sheets
 now i want to load following pattern

```
s1(sheet)---->a(table),
s2---->b,
s3---->c,
s4---->d,
s5---->e
```

Comment: What about foreach loop container?

Answer (score 0):

From the Excel source you can select the sheets. You may need to have as many Excel Sources as sheets you have on your workbook

[image]

Comment: No! Disagree. You need only one excel source but Foreach loop container.

Comment: whoa!, that's another option but arguably at best. I would rather load all the sheets at once in parallel than serial.

Comment: If you want to go for parallel processing, then go ahead. But still, foreach container is for looping though, files, sheets and folders. If you want to process 100 Excel sheets in a file, will you go for 100 excel connections? I don't think so.

Comment: but my task is i want to load table with single excel source using "Foreach loop container" pls help me

Comment: you then need to configure the properties of your excel source as follows: 1) set "Access Mode" property to "OpenRowset From Variable" and 2) set "OpenRowsetVariable" property to the name of the variable that holds the name of the sheet to process.